# Can an adjective modify the entire sentence?

Tags: adjectives, clauses, modifiers

I came across the following sentence, and I was so curious about “effective next Monday.”

> Mr. Michael has resigned his position as senior sales manager, effective next Monday.

Effective is indeed an adjective.

How could we place an adjective in this position of the sentence?

I understand the meaning of the sentence. The word “effective” is to describe his “resignation‘. However, I just don’t know why an adjective could be placed here.

Could anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: Your example and the related specific question you’ve asked about it doesn’t match the title. In your example, *effective* doesn’t modify the whole sentence.

Comment: @Lawrence A clause, then; omit *We regret to announce that*.  Unless the regret begins on Monday, heh.

Comment: @AntonSherwood Would you mind editing the question directly? Answers are based on the question without reference to comments, and the Q&A as a whole is archived, while comments are sometimes removed without notice.

Comment: @Lawrence Okay, done, I hope I have not distorted anything.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your comments. So “effective” is to modify the noun class (that....)? Thanks

Answer (score -2):

There would be no mystery if the sentence were instead

> Mr. Michael has given his resignation, effective next Monday.

There, the adjective clearly applies to *resignation*.

And of course there is little practical difference between these two:

> Mr. Michael has given his resignation.
>
> Mr. Michael has resigned.

At some point, people started to substitute the latter for the former, without thought to the poor orphaned adjective.

A form I've seen occasionally, without the “dangling adjective” problem, is

> ... with effect from Monday.

Comment: Hi, so this sentence is actually poorly written?

Comment: Formally yes, but I'd say it has become idiomatic.